# Installing Ubuntu on an External Harddrive. Invalid password

Tags: grub2, login, password, external-hdd, tty

This is my first time working with Ubuntu, and I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.10 on an external 1 TB harddrive. I set up my username and password using Ubuntiquity as something simple. Username: haley. Password: test.

After copying files to the drive, I get a prompt to login. When I use the credentials above I keep getting "Invalid password, please try again". I can't reboot into GRUB because I'm trying to install Ubuntu in the first place. I can't use the TTY cause I can't login.

My PC's OS system is Windows 10, and I have been using diskpart to clean the harddrive and Rufus to "burn" the i386 ISO file onto a USB. I'm using BIOS to boot from the USB.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: There is not enough info here to help you. Im assuming you have a pc with an os on it already (what os)  and your trying to setup an external drive to boot ubuntu from ? what media are you using to do the install dvd or usb. ?

Comment: If in fact you completed the install process the system should restart and you should see the login screen . the media you used to do the install is no longer needed. but if you restarted and are trying to log in and it says your credentials are not correct your only option is to start over format the drive and reinstall agian :(. be carefull of the state of num-lock during install and after restart to make sure its off you can try test in caps to make sure this isnt the case currently

Comment: Are you installing in BIOS or UEFI boot mode? May be best to see details, you can run from Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: I added more information above. I hope this helps! I haven't been able to restart my system yet. There isn't even an option to restart from the login screen. Just shut down, but with no shut down button.

Comment: How would I use boot info without logging in?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up attempting to install Ubuntu 16.10 on my external drive at least 10 times. I had the ISO file on a USB and would boot on it and hit "Try Ubuntu". After that I connected to the internet and proceeded to install Ubuntu. I would partition 10000 MB to a swap area on the ext HDD, and the rest of the drive I partitioned to a primary ext4 assigned to the root of the drive. However, every time I did this I would be seemingly be locked out of Ubuntu as described above.

Turns out the best answer was actually the easiest one. While I was using Ubuntu 16.10, I happen to realize that Ubuntu 17.04 is the most recent version released and 16.10 would be expiring in July. So, I attempt to install 17.04 - setting up the drive just as described above -, and it worked with flying colors! Just remember to safely eject your hardware after use.

I hope this helps any other Ubuntu noobs out there that encounter a similar issue.